# Propagator for Free Particle in Energy Basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, propagator

I'm continuing [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269627/247238) question because the answer to this is not helping me. As the OP said the propagator in the problem should be given in energy basis :

$$U(t)=\sum_{\alpha=\pm}\int_0^\infty |E,\alpha\rangle\langle E,\alpha | e^{-iEt/\hbar} dE$$

But if you derive it from the expression of momentum basis :
$$U(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |p\rangle\langle p|e^{-i E(p)t/\hbar}dp$$
by substituting the value of $E=E(p)$ then you get an additional factor for density of state.

I'm asking for a solution that starts from the energy basis such that the density of the state came out automatically. As the propagator is just
$$U(t)=e^{-iHt/\hbar}$$

Comment: Integrating over $dp$ and over $dE$ is not the same thing - the results differ by the Jacobian, which in this context is called *density-of-states*.

Comment: $U(t)$ is not a propagator, it seems to be your evolution operator. Propagators are a different concept

Comment: @ohneVal It's the way defined in R Shankar's book.

Comment: I care about the terminology, because a lot of problems are just miscommunication, check the Wikipedia for propagator. It is not standard and there is no need to call that propagator when it already has a name which doesn't collide with anything else.

Comment: @ohneVal I'm not concerned with the naming. Call whatever you want to call. I have read it as in R Shankar's book.

Comment: You should perhaps the cite the page number and book in the text of the question